# jquery for loop thru div

Tags: jquery, loops

would like to use a loop to express this ..

```
$("div:nth-child(3)").css({"left": "5px"});
$("div:nth-child(2)").css({"left": "215px"});
$("div:nth-child(1)").css({"left": "425px"});
```

how can each be referenced...

```
var x=0;
$("div").each(function(){
   x=x+100;
   $(this).css('position','absolute'); 
   $(this).css({"left": "xpx"});  // not sure about this line
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x=0;
$("div").each(function(){
   x = x + 100;
   $(this).css({'position':'absolute', 'left': x + 'px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want

```
$(this).css({"left": x+"px"});
```

Comment: do you have any suggestions for books or sites for learning jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
$(this).css("left", x);
```

You don't need to add `px`; jQuery will add it automatically.

If you do want to explicitly add a unit, you can use string concatenation:

```
$(this).css("left", x + "px");
```

Comment: Wrong.  You don't need the `:` (as long as you don't use braces to make an object literal)

Answer (score 0):

```
var xx=0;
$("div").each(function(){
    xx+=100;
    $(this).css('position','absolute'); 
    $(this).css({"left": xx+"px"}); 
});
```

Try not to use 'x' as a variableName, might be confusing in later stadia. Fixed your code.

Comment: How is `xx` a better variable name than `x`?

Comment: Using 'x' as a variable name often confuses me when programming. It's not a bad variable name, but I don't like using it.

Comment: x marks the spot. no reason but I use x most of the time to begin. then y and then z. was taught that way by math people.

Comment: True, it does hit the spot perfectly in this example. I used to use variablenames like 'x' and 'y' a lot, but quit it after programming math-like software. I was confusing my variable 'x' with my global variable 'x' or 'x-value' so me and my team stopped using 'x', 'y', 'r', 's', etc as names of our variables. Habits ;-)